# Sometimes I got e.getCause() == null when I trying send a message through JMS

Tags: java, exception, jms

i have a piece of code to sending messages through JMS like this below

```
public String sendMessage(@Header("JMSType") final String messageType, @Header("url") final String destinationURL,
        @Header("header") final String header, @Header("pid") final String pid,
        @Header("dataOne") final String dataOne, @Header("msgVersion") final String msgVersion,
        @Body final String originalPayload) throws HttpException, InvalidMsgContentException,
        ServiceUnavailableException {

    if (messageType != null && destinationURL != null) {
        final String urlSuffix = messageType.toLowerCase().replace("_", ""); // NOPMD
        String destination = destinationURL;
        if (!destinationURL.substring(destinationURL.length() - 1).equals("/")) {
            destination += "/";
        }
        destination += urlSuffix;

        if (nullCheck(pid) || nullCheck(originalPayload)) {
            throw new InvalidMsgContentException(String.format(
                    "Null or empty value: pid: %s, payload: %s", pid,
                    originalPayload));
        }

        final String payload = addHeader(header, pid, dataOne, msgVersion, messageType, originalPayload);

        try {
            final URL url = new URL(destination);

            final HttpURLConnection conn;
            if (proxy == null) {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            } else {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
            }

            log.info("sending '" + payload + "' to " + destination);
            send(conn, payload);
            return "";
        } catch (final InvalidMsgContentException | ServiceUnavailableException e) {
            final String msg = "send to " + destination + " failed: ";
            log.error(msg + e.getCause());
            throw e;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            final String msg = "send to " + destination + " failed: ";
            log.error(msg + e.getCause());
            throw new HttpException(msg, e);
        }
    }
    final String msg = "Invalid parameters: messageType: " + messageType + "; destinationURL: " + destinationURL;
    log.error(msg);
    throw new InvalidMsgContentException("Invalid parameters: JMSType: " + messageType
            + "; destinationURL: " + destinationURL);
}
```

Sometimes i see in log a message;

"send to https://destination.com/raport failed: null"

It means that I got exception with e.getCause() == null from the part of that code.

How I can manage with this situation or maybe I'm doing something in wrong way and I dont catch some exception

?

Please help me.

Best regards,
mq

Comment: There has never been such a guarantee that the cause will always be present. Maybe you misunderstand that method's meaning. Anyway, I would strongly advise logging the full exception. `log.warn("sending...failed", e);`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this bug in the short time or add log for full exception. Have you got any idea which exception is thrown?

Comment: Your question makes me conclude that you don't understand your problem. You are logging the wrong thing, that is why you don't see which exception is thrown. When you start logging the right thing (as noted above), then you shall know what exception is being thrown.

Comment: You have absolutly right but as I mentioned before it is not easy to replace existing code with new one and it hard to reproduce this bug. Im also not an author of this method and of course I can change loging for the correct way and it looks that I need to do it and than I will see what is happend ther. I had hope that someone looks at this code a get me a quick answer how to fix the bug.

Comment: To fix a bug you need to know the cause of a bug. To figure out the cause of a bug you need to do a proper investigation, which starts with fixing the bad logging so you at least get some kind of information.

Comment: It seems that whatever is throwing the exception is not setting the datum that getCause() expects to find, so if you cannot change that code, there is nothing you can do about that.  However, since you re-throw, or throw a new one with the original chained, something higher in the call stack should trap that exception and deal with it, e.g by printStackTrace().